# Convert Navigation Button into Back Button?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I, want to convert my navigation icon into back icon when I open my contact us fragment. for achieving this I have put this code.

```
@Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_dashboard);

        if (f instanceof ContactUsFragment) {
            notifications.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noti_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notifications.setEnabled(true);
            mActionBarTitle.setText("Contact Us");
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.navigtion_back);
            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.navigtion_back);
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
```

By this code when I am on Contact us fragment my navigation icon act as back icon. but the issue is my navigation icon not converted into back icon by this code. I searched on stack overflow and tried out these three codes to convert navigation icon into back icon but all three didn't work.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.navigtion_back);
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.navigtion_back);
```

Comment: what happens now when you press the navigation button?

Comment: It act as back button. but navigation icon not convert into back button when I am contact us fragment.

Comment: so your issue is with the icon not the behaviour of the navigation button?

Comment: Yes, Exactly I tried all the things but my icon not getting changed.